# Using frontcamera to display the user with a canvasGUI and take screenshots

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera, xcode6, screenshot

I am quite new to iOS programming. I'd like to build an app which uses the frontcamera of an ipad or iphone to display the user holding it (just like making a selfie). But there should also be some kind of dynamic HUD, which gets displayed over the camera-view. And I'd like to take a screenshot of this like every 30seconds without user interaction.

Well, thats pretty much you might think, and I already made my iPad to display a camera and take a photo with it. But I have no idea how to make a whole thing and meet my requirements altogether.

Can you please give me some hints where to start? Or an exampleProject with a similar requirement?

- Is there something like a canvas (like the html5 canvas), which I can use for programming the hud (it should refresh every 5 seconds)
- How can I put this hud over the cameraview?
- which library should I use to merge two pictures (in my case the photo and the picture of the hud)

Every hint is welcomed! Thanks in advance.